# I need to extract the territory of Uzbekistan from the arcgis webmap

Tags: arcgis-js-api

I'm using @arcgis/core. I need to extract the territory of Uzbekistan from the arcgis webmap, the remaining areas must be removed

i need to check again if the districts have the places i have defined how can i do that how can i know if the district boundaries are visible when zoomed in

I have another question why @arcgis/core quasar project keeps giving me an error, is there any conflict to resolve?

These are the things I called

```
import ArcGISMap from "@arcgis/core/webmap";
import MapView from "@arcgis/core/views/MapView";
import esriConfig from "@arcgis/core/config";
import Basemap from '@arcgis/core/Basemap'
import BasemapGallery from '@arcgis/core/widgets/BasemapGallery'
import Expand from '@arcgis/core/widgets/Expand'
import VectorTileLayer from '@arcgis/core/layers/VectorTileLayer'
import Graphic from '@arcgis/core/Graphic';
import { SimpleFillSymbol } from '@arcgis/core/symbols';
import { SimpleRenderer } from '@arcgis/core/renderers';
import { onMounted, ref } from "vue";
```

```
const myMap = ref(null);

onMounted(() =\> {
const basemap = new Basemap({
baseLayers: \[
new VectorTileLayer({
portalItem: {

id: "36551d7048d643618026014f3075327b", // Community basemap style
},
}),
\],
});

const map = new ArcGISMap({
basemap: basemap,
});

const view = new MapView({
container: myMap.value,
map: map,
center: \[65.23, 41.32\], // O'zbekiston markazidagi koordinatlar
zoom: 7,
constraints: {
snapToZoom: false,
},
});

const uzShape = { // O'zbekiston hududlarini geometriyasi
type: "polygon",
rings: \[\[
\[55.9753, 37.1707\],
\[73.1761, 37.1707\],
\[73.1761, 45.5907\],
\[55.9753, 45.5907\],
\[55.9753, 37.1707\]
\]\],
spatialReference: {
  wkid: 4326 // WGS 1984 koordinat tizimi
}
};

const uzSymbol = new SimpleFillSymbol({
color: \[0, 0, 255, 0.2\], // Kengayish rangi va nozikligi

outline: {
color: "blue", // Chegaraning rangi
width: 1 // Chegaraning kengligi
}
});

const uzGraphic = new Graphic({
geometry: uzShape,
symbol: uzSymbol
});

const uzLayer = map.layers.getItemAt(0); // Birinchi layerni olamiz
if (uzLayer && uzLayer.hasOwnProperty('renderer')) {
uzLayer.renderer = new SimpleRenderer({ symbol: uzSymbol });
uzLayer.graphics.add(uzGraphic);
}
else{
console.log('ishlamayapti')
}\
```

Comment: What you mean with extract?, you want to get the information in some format or just view on the map the Uzbekistan data?. Can you add a link to `@arcgis/core quasar project`?.